# setting SecurityManager Permissions from the java code

Tags: java, security, applet, socketexception, policyfiles

I am running a Applet which does Socket connection i am getting 
Exception  `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 connect,resolve)` 
I googled and found out that it is because of Java's security manager so i added

```
grant{    
    java.net.SocketPermission xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 "connect";
    java.net.SocketPermission xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 "resolve";
}
```

inside java.policy at C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security using policytool.exe successfully worked

But I wanted this to be done programmatically so i did the following

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction() { public Object run() throws Exception {                                                                         
       socketchannel1 = SocketChannel.open();
       socketchannel1.connect( new InetSocketAddress( xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 80 ) );
return null;} });}
```

here i am telling securityManager not to touch the code inside run this is also successful 
But Now I want to know if there is any other method with which i can specifically add SocketPermission to connect,resolve 
with Policy.setpolicy or something like setpermission or modifying the above itself.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Forget policy files, they are not practical at time of deployment.  To get trust, digitally sign the applet.  Also, tags don't cost anything and help people to find your question and later answers, so it pays to add more than one.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson I didnt know these tags were there

Comment: I usually find them by typing key words and seeing what pops up as the suggestions.  E.G. That is how I found [tag:policyfiles], never knew it existed before today. ;)